# How can I open a YouTube video link directly from an Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I want to play a YouTube video on a click of a *Button*, but I am getting an action dialog window that I don't want to show. I want that the YouTube video link should open directly in the YouTube app on a Button click rather than showing this "choose action" window:

[image]

How is it possible?

Code:

```
 playVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzSTpdcs-EI")));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the package name of the YouTube application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzSTpdcs-EI"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Probably want to wrap that in a check for "com.google.android.youtube" on the device? If user has disabled youtube for whatever reason, any idea what happens when this intent runs?

Answer (score 3):

You can launch an intent directly to the YouTube app using the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzSTpdcs-EI"));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity(intent);
```

Wrap this code inside the *try catch* to avoid exceptions if youtube is not present in the device.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best method is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

The id is *YykjpeuMNEk* in the URL
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YykjpeuMNEk.

Comment: Why `vnd.youtube`? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://XXXX), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

A [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) suggestion without any YouTube app on device error handling:

```
try {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube")
    startActivity(intent)
}
catch (e : Exception) {
    Snackbar.make(
        requireView(),
        "Don't you have YouTube? For real?",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```